# Use x/y coordinates to set bounds of a moving particle

Tags: android, coordinates, screen-size, screen-density

I have two bitmaps that I draw onto the center of a canvas:
One is only a background, it's a spirit level in top view which doesnt move. The second one is a bitmap looking like a "air bubble". When the user tilts the phone, the sensors read the tilt and the air bubble moves according to the sensor values along the x-axis. However, I need to make sure that the air bubble doesnt move too far, e.g out of the background-bitmap.
So I tried to which x coordinate the bubble can travel to, 
before I have to set xPos = xPos -1 using trial and error
This works fine on my device.

To clarify: On my phone, the air bubble could move to the coordinate x = 50 from the middle of the screen. This would be the point, where the bitmap is at the very left of the background spirit level. 
On a larger phone, the position x = 50 is too far left, and therefore looking like the air bubble travelled out of the water level.

Now I've tried following:
I calculated the area in % in which the air bubble can move. Let's say that
is 70% of the entire width of the bitmap. So I tried to calculate the two x boundary values:

`leftBoundary = XmiddlePoint - (backgroundBitmap.getWidth() * 0.35);
 rightBoundary = XmiddlePoint + (backgroundBitmap.getWidth() * 0.35);`

...which doesnt work when testing with different screen sizes :(

Is it possible to compensate for different screen sizes and densities using absolute coordinates or do I have to rethink my idea?

If you need any information that I forgot about, please let me know. If this question has already been answered, I would appreciate a link :) Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I load my bitmaps like this:

```
private Bitmap backgroundBitmap;
private static final int BITMAP_WIDTH = 1898;
private static final int BITMAP_HEIGHT = 438;

public class SimulationView extends View implements SensorEventListener{
public SimulationView(Context context){
Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources, R.mipmap.backgroundImage);
backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(map, BITMAP_WIDTH, BITMAP_HEIGHT, true; 
}
```

and draw it like this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, XmiddlePoint - BITMAP_WIDTH / 2, YmiddlePont - BITMAP_HEIGHT / 2, null);
}
```

backgroundBitmap.getWidth() and getHeight() prints out the correct sizes.
Calculating like mentioned above would return following boundaries:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity)  getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    //which prints out width = 2392
    xMiddlePoint = width / 2;
    // = 1196
    leftBoundary = xMiddlePoint - (BITMAP.getWidth()* 0.35);
    // = 531,7
```

However, when I use trial and error, the right x coordinate seems to be at around 700.

Comment: Your implementation looks alright. Can you log what the values output and what they might be given the screen size? Can you confirm that the bitmap width is correct and the view has been properly inflated before calculating the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across a great explanation on how to fix my issue [here.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29750/fitting-android-game-to-different-screen-sizes)
As user AgentKnopf explained, you have to scale coordinates or bitmaps like this:

> X = (targetScreenWidth / defaultScreenWidth) * defaultXCoordinate
>
> Y = (targetScreenHeight / defaultScreenHeight) * defaultYCoordinate

which, in my case, translates to:

```
int defaultScreenWidth = 1920;
int defaultXCoordinate = 333;
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
leftBoundary = (displayWidth / defaultScreenWidth) * defaultXCoordinates
```